# Dismissing to root view controller without showing nested / intermediate view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I want to dismiss all intermediate child view controllers and show the root view controller.

The following piece of code works:
`self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

However, I can briefly see the intermediate view controller flash before it animates to dismiss to the root view controller. Any way, it just directly animates to the root view controller?

Comment: Just set `self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)` `animated: false`

Comment: are they in navigation controller or presented modally? If in navigation controller,             `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)`

Comment: @KishanBhatiya already tried that, same issue.

Comment: @KeshuR. There is an intermediate navigation view controller so this won't give me the root view controller. However, I have also tried to reach the root VC passing through all the navigation controllers and same issue.

Comment: Are you presenting view controllers modally or pushing them in navigation controller?

Comment: @KeshuR. Root View Controller ~>  Modal Pres to VC A ~> Modal Pres to VC B (embedded in nav controller) ~>  Push to VC C (Now need to go from VC C to root directly)

Comment: Well the easiest way would be to set the rootViewController again.

Comment: Well, I can even present the the root VC directly then. However, the animation won't be correct. i.e from top to bottom.

Comment: @aledap No that would be wrong. changing root view controller will dismiss and clear all navigation stack . Whereas presenting the root view controller will not clear the current view controllers and it will just push the root view controller as a new view controller on top of them. Understand the difference.

Comment: Try to set rootViewController using `let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController) `          
`let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate`
`appdelegate.window!.rootViewController = navigationController`

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing out the difference. And yes I can no longer see the nested VC by setting the root VC again, however there is no animation. I guess I'll just have to make do. Thanks.

Comment: @aledap i post my comment as answer so if it is solved your issue then accept and upvote it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to set rootViewController again as follow:

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController) 
let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate 
appdelegate.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call

```
self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

animation false if you don't want to see intermediate controllers
it it still flash you can hide other presented views or make their alpha 0

like

```
if let first = presentedViewController,
        let second = first.presentedViewController,
            let third = second.presentedViewController {
                second.view.alpha = 0
                first.view.alpha = 0
                    third.dismiss(animated: false)

     }
```

or set directly to rootViewController

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = YourViewController
```

or in IOS 13 Scene delegate

```
 let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first
        if let getSceneDelegate : SceneDelegate = (scene?.delegate as? SceneDelegate) {
            getSceneDelegate.window?.rootViewController = YourController
        }
```

Comment: No, the intermediate view controller still flashes before the root view controller shows up. The only difference is now the root view controller just shows up without animation.